# JWT::ExpiredSignature raised when validating token from getUserIdentityTokenAsync

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin

Our system is authenticating users by following [these validation steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/validate-an-identity-token) on a token generated by the [getUserIdentityTokenAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.mailbox?view=outlook-js-1.5#getuseridentitytokenasync-callback--usercontext-) method.

These tokens are failing the following check

> Current time is between the times specified in the nbf and exp claims. The nbf claim specifies the earliest time that the token is considered valid, and the exp claim specifies the expiration time for the token. It is recommended to allow for some variation in clock settings between servers.

Our logs show these tokens being invalid by several hours

```
Current Time: 2020-04-10 17:02:11 +0000,
Valid Start: 2020-04-09 14:46:31 +0000,
Valid End: 2020-04-09 23:16:31 +0000,
```

We are validating these times as such:

```rb
    def timeframe_valid?
      PAYLOAD_WIGGLE_TIME = 900                                                         
      if @payload.present?                                                         
        now = Time.now.to_i                                                        
        payload_valid_start = @payload[:nbf] - PAYLOAD_VALID_WIGGLE_TIME           
        payload_valid_expire = @payload[:exp] + PAYLOAD_VALID_WIGGLE_TIME          

        if now < payload_valid_start || now > payload_valid_expire                 
          # handle invalid token...                                                                      
        end                                                                        
      end                                                                          
    end
```

We are making a unique call to `getUserIdentityTokenAsync` before each api request. Since we are  seeing such a large difference in the time window for a valid token and the time it is validated, my best guess is that users are leaving the add-in open for long periods of time without refreshing. For some reason, when they return, `getUserIdentityTokenAsync` is not returning a new token, but rather the old one that is already expired.

Is there any way to force `getUserIdentityToken` to issue a new token after one has long since expired without a hard refresh of the add-in?

Comment: What is your scenario for making a unique call to getUserIdentityToken before each api request? The token from getUserIdentityTokenAsync can be used for subsequent API calls and refreshed when it expires. Documentation describing this can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/implement-sso-in-outlook-add-in

Comment: our reason for calling `getUserIdentityToken` before each request is we are trusting the Outlook Api to always return a valid token (that is not expired). This does not seem to be the case since we _do_ request the token each time we make an api request to our backend, and that token is failing our validation above. Your suggestion is to use SSO instead correct? That documentation suggests the identity token is also a valid way of identifying the user. You say it can be refreshed when it expires. How can I manually refresh the token?

Comment: Which version of Exchange and which Outlook client(s) are you seeing the invalid token? You should be getting a valid token each time you call the API